# Recover deleted files in SSD/flash storage

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, ssd, data-recovery, ipad

Is it possible to recover deleted files in SSD/flash storage in ipad? I heard that it is not possible to undelete files in SSD in newer windows OS (windows 7 and 8), but older mac and ios does not use trunk command to replace old file sector with blank data.

The files in icloud were accidently deleted from ipad, with IOS 8.1.1. It was synched with windows machine. I was able to recover some deleted images and phone numbers from Dr fone. It only recovered files generated in ipad but did not recover other documents synched from my windows machine. I need to recover extremely important word documents. Is it possible to recover with any other tool?

It was also synched in windows7 machine with magnetic disk. I used recuva, but the file generated by it was not readable. I also used R-studio in windows 7 but It found about 500 thousand files which was almost impossible to find the required document. The sectors might have been overwritten in windows machine. The only way left is recovering from ipad.

Any geeky method can be suggested.

Comment: Its not clear how your problem is connected to an iOS device.  It sounds like the deleted document you are trying to recover was already replaced by other data.  Its is indeed possible to recover data from a SSD provided the data has not been replaced or wiped through a TRIM operation.

Comment: The synched file deleted in windows7 is not recovered, but there is chance that file in ipad SSD can be recovered as it does not uses TRUNK. But how? are there any tools to do? or it can be done through some programming?

Comment: iOS devices do not use a SSD.  The storage they use is an entirely different type of flash memory compared to what SSD devices use.  You already tried to recover the file from the iOS device and failed to do that, part of the data is already been replaced, file fragmentation isn't an issue on flash memory devices doesn't mean it still doesn't exist.

Comment: Could you please suggest any method or tool to do that? I have extremely important data to recover and I cannot stop looking for it.

Comment: You can use all the tools in the world.  If one tool already failed to recover the data, another tool that recovered deleted data, isn't going to change the data was already replaced with other data.  Software recommendations are specifically not on topic here at Superuser.

Comment: does this look about time for me to again mention… "any data not stored in at least 3 distinct locations ought to be considered temporary" ?

Answer (score -2):

Deep search can find files that are removed from FAT. Try different tools, you may never know which might help you. try easeus, R-studio, steller, phoneix, recuva, remo recover like software to recover data.But remo recover software had helped me when i accidently deleted all the partitions while installing linux.
If you tried all the tools available tools and still unsuccessful then you have to seek professional help like sending the hard disk to forensic lab.